# C++: confusing variadic template causing "candidate function not viable" error

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, amd-rocm

I was trying to port a CUDA project into ROCm platform which make use of C++ templates extensively. During this process, I am getting following compilation error

```
/root/warp-ctc/include/detail/gpu_ctc.h:381:5: error: no matching function for call to 'hipLaunchKernelGGL'
    hipLaunchKernelGGL((prepare_stable_SM_kernel<ProbT, VT>), dim3(grid_size), dim3(NT), 0, stream_, ctc_helper::identity<ProbT>(), probs_,
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.....
.....
/opt/rocm/hip/include/hip/hcc_detail/functional_grid_launch.hpp:138:13: note: candidate function [with Args = <ctc_helper::identity<float, float>, float *,
      float *, int, int>, F = void (*)(ctc_helper::identity<float, float>, float *, float *, int, int)] not viable: no overload of 'prepare_stable_SM_kernel'
      matching 'void (*)(ctc_helper::identity<float, float>, float *, float *, int, int)' for 1st argument
inline void hipLaunchKernelGGL(F kernel, const dim3& numBlocks, const dim3& dimBlocks,
```

for [following piece of C++ code](https://github.com/harish2704/warp-ctc/blob/4f3806cf8d7431c5c4cef42cca9c1471e56d7ddd/include/detail/gpu_ctc.h#L381)

```cpp
hipLaunchKernelGGL((prepare_stable_SM_kernel<ProbT, VT>),
                   dim3(grid_size),
                   dim3(NT),
                   0,
                   stream_,
                   ctc_helper::identity<ProbT>(),
                   probs_,
                   denoms_,
                   out_dim_,
                   num_elements);
```

where `hipLaunchKernelGGL` is [defined as](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP/blob/59c54da4f01758581d087bba94e476e39eed7c14/include/hip/hcc_detail/functional_grid_launch.hpp#L137)

```
template <typename... Args, typename F = void (*)(Args...)>
inline void hipLaunchKernelGGL(F kernel,
                               const dim3& numBlocks,
                               const dim3& dimBlocks,
                               std::uint32_t sharedMemBytes,
                               hipStream_t stream,
                               Args... args) {

// ...
// ...
}
```

and `prepare_stable_SM_kernel` is [defined as](https://github.com/harish2704/warp-ctc/blob/4f3806cf8d7431c5c4cef42cca9c1471e56d7ddd/include/detail/gpu_ctc_kernels.h#L473)

```
template <typename ProbT, int VT = 1, typename Op>
__global__ void prepare_stable_SM_kernel(Op f, ProbT* probs,
                                         const ProbT* const col_max,
                                         int alphabet_size,
                                         int count) {
// ...
}
```

Anyone please help me by providing some hints to fix this problem.

Comment: What is `(prepare_stable_SM_kernel<ProbT, VT>)`?  Can you turn this into a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver: The fact is that, I am a beginner in C++11 and I was not able fully to understand the code. I have updated the question with that definition  of `prepare_stable_SM_kernel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was fixed by adding a third parameter `ctc_helper::identity<ProbT>` to `prepare_stable_SM_kernel` function

Ref https://github.com/harish2704/warp-ctc/commit/c7ec45febc9c0077ffa35932b3d11a05daf8bf7c#diff-1e372cfc8edab301b6c284e9db8dbf68